# Replace %20 with an empty space

Tags: php

I have the following function :

```
function remove() {
        $value_1 = "Patrick%20Kaka%20M";
        $value_2 = "%";
        $value_3 = " ";
        $new_value = str_replace($value_3, $value_2, $value_1);
        echo 'New value is : ....  '.$new_value.'<br>';
    }
```

I want the value one to output as Partick Kaka M but it keeps on failing. 
Please advise on how I can implement it well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `urldecode()`

`echo urldecode('Patrick%20Kaka%20M');`